# quick fix for JSP with in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, quickfix

I'm running Eclipse 3.4 java enterprise adition and writing JSP pages with it. It does not appear to support quick fix, for example ArrayList ourList; comes up as an error but there isn't a quick fix option to add the import java.util.ArrayList statement. Is there a way to improve quick fix capabilities, or another set of Eclipse Plugins that provides quick fix for jsp?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the Ctrl+spacebar and it automatically added the import for me.  Maybe that's good enough?

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) is something that you could try for improved JSP editing.  I think it's only about $30 for a version with the JSP editing.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from this particular problem (which you could solve by using **Eclipse for Java EE** which has the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) integrated), this implies that you're writing raw Java code inside a JSP file. This is considered bad practice. JSP is a view technology wherein you ought to control the flow and output using taglibs (e.g. [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)) and to access the data using EL. Raw Java code actually belongs in a real Java class, like a Servlet, Filter, Javabean, DAO, Utility, etcetera. Keep the JSP clean from scriptlets. If you ever need to do something which isn't doable using taglibs/EL, then the particular code most likely belongs in a Java class.

Creating an `ArrayList` ought to be done inside a Servlet class, either directly or indirectly (business class). Use the `doGet()` to preprocess data for display and use the `doPost()` to postprocess data after submit. Inside the JSP you can iterate over an `ArrayList` using the JSTL [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag.

Good luck.